# ConfigParser listing hosts in different sections of an inventory file?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I have an inventory file of the format.

```
[web]
web1
web2
web3

[loadbalancer]
lb1
lb2
lb3

[admin]
adm1
adm2
adm3
```

I want to be able to read hosts from various sections of the file. So for instance to list all the sections I tried.

```
import ConfigParser
parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('hosts.cfg')
parser.sections()
```

But this printed all the servers with the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server_audit.py", line 55, in <module>
    parser.read('hosts.cfg')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ConfigParser.py", line 286, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ConfigParser.py", line 510, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: hosts.cfg
    [line  2]: 'web1\n'
    [line  3]: 'web2\n'
    [line  4]: 'web3\n'
    [line  7]: 'lb1\n'
    [line  8]: 'lb2\n'
    [line  9]: 'lb3\n'
    [line 12]: 'adm1\n'
    [line 13]: 'adm2\n'
    [line 14]: 'adm3\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

The config file needs to have the form:

```
[web]
web1 = value1
web2 = value2
web3 = value3
```

Etc.

So, the left hand side is the 'key' that is used for look up.  The right hand side is the value for that key. Example:

```
[web]
web1 = http://www.example.org
```

Comment: Are you saying I'm forced to have a key-value pair? I've tried using the allow_no_value option but I think it won't accept this because I'm using python 2.6.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a key-value pair.  You can do multi values per key though key=value1,value2,value3. The allow_no_value is to accept keys without values

Comment: FYI:Looks like similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342045/configparser-and-section-with-values-without-keys

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks like I'll have to stick with this method for now.